# Derivative question calculus

Tags: calculus

How would I figure out the following question.

Find the values of x at which the rate of change of $y=30+28x^2+16x^3-2x^4$ with respect to $x$ is zero.

Do I have to take the derivative and set it to zero or something else.

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Yes, the rate of change is the derivative, so you gotta set the derivative equal to zero.

Comment: Hmm but how many times would I take derivative only one time or several times.

Comment: Just like ciceksizkakarot said ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first derivative is the same thing as the rate of change, so the question essentially says to find when the first derivative equals zero. 
So you have
$$
\frac {dy} {dx} = -8x(x-7)(x+1) = 0,
$$
so the x-coordinates where the rate of change is zero are $x = 0, 7,$ and $-1$.